# Do I have to purify the submit form data when creating mysqli connection based on user input?

Tags: php, mysql, security, mysqli

I am trying to write a php installer for my client to install my php program. What I mean is, my client can run domain.com/myscript/install/index.php, enter the database name, password hostname etc and once the form is submitted, my installer script will connect to the mySQL database (based on user's input), then create some tables etc.

ie.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($_POST['hostname'],$_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['port']);
```

so, I wonder in this case, is it necessary to purify $_POST?

Comment: Yes! It's good hygiene for one and you have no idea how it might be exploited so don't assume.

Comment: Always a good idea to purify user-entered data, even if you think only a trusted user would ever use it.

Comment: I wonder which php function I should use, because at this point I can't use mysqli_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always sanitize user input, no matter what. You don't need `mysqli_real_escape_string` at this point, that function only escapes certain characters for safe inserts into tables. Absolutely not what you need right now. Use [PHP's built-in filter functions](http://php.net/ref.filter).

```
<?php

$sanitize_string = array(
  'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
  'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH,
);

$user_input = filter_input_array(
  INPUT_POST,
  'hostname' => $sanitize_string, // You could also use the IP one, check for persistent, ...
  'username' => $sanitize_string,
  'password' => FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, // It's going to be hashed, who cares!
  'port'     => array(
     'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
     'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
     'options' => array('min_range' => 666, 'max_range' => 3600),
   ),
   true
);

foreach ($user_input as $input) {
  if (!$input) { // Either NULL or FALSE, we don't care!
    trigger_error("No no my dear!", E_USER_ERROR);
  }
}

list($host, $user, $pass, $port) = $user_input;
$mysqli = new \mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $port);

?>
```

Comment: do I have to call the filter_var?

Comment: You can use `filter_var()` for each variable, are as shown above directly the `filter_input_array() function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're handling the SQL, you wouldn't do it in the traditional sense.  Rather, you need to make sure it conforms to the MySQL interface options.  In other words, posting '127.0.0.1;delete from users' isn't going to pose a problem, but it also won't create a valid connection.